# Place et fonction d'une expression : « et il souligna » (Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir, Georges Courteline)

Tags: ordre-des-mots, ponctuation

On trouve cette expression dans le texte suivant (*Messieurs les Ronds-de-Cuir*, Georges Courteline).

> — En effet, fit alors M. de La Hourmerie que le joli toupet de
> l’expéditionnaire avait démonté un moment ; la section ne saurait tarder à se prononcer, et je n’attends que le retour du dossier pour soumettre à la signature du président de la République le décret d’autorisation. Si monsieur (et il souligna), qui est si exactement renseigné, veut bien faire dès à présent le nécessaire, nul doute que je sois en état de vous satisfaire
> rapidement.

L'italique est celle du texte. Il s'agit sans aucun doute de l'italique expressive telle que définie dans cette source.

> ([traduirÉcrire](https://xn--traduircrire-heb.com/quand-faut-il-ecrire-en-italique/)) L’italique facultatif
>
> L’italique peut aussi avoir une fonction expressive ou subjective en permettant d’insister sur un terme ou de le dénoncer.

Dans le LBU 14<sup>e</sup> édition, on trouve ceci à la remarque R1 88.

> Dans un texte manuscrit ou dactylographié, l'équivalent normal de l'italique est le
> soulignement.

Comme la parenthèse se trouve avant la virgule on peut se demander si elle ne porterait pas sur le mot « monsieur » ; cependant, l'italique qui suit est une marque de soulignement et donc il semble plus probable que la parenthèse porte sur le texte souligné au moyen de l'italique.

1. Y a-t-il un sens particulier derrière cette pratique qui semble revenir à souligner deux fois ?
2. Si la parenthèse porte bien sur le texte en italique, n'est-il pas plus logique de placer la virgule derrière cette parenthèse et non devant ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147220/discussion-on-question-by-lph-place-et-fonction-dune-expression--et-il-souli); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @anonymous2 Since the purpose of comments is to ask for clarification (my first comment) and to suggest improvement (a further comment pointing to the fact that the OP mentions italics in the quoted text, but does not reproduce those, I wonder why those comments have been removed.  Just for the record since I mention those 2 facts in my answer (a note that I did not get an answer to my first request) and reproduced the correct quote in the body of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Nous sommes dans un dialogue. Comme dans tout dialogue, il y a des paroles prononcées par les personnages créés par l'auteur, et des indications personnelles de l'auteur qui sont des incises.

Extrait de l'article  [Proposition incise](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_incise) de Wikipedia :

> En syntaxe, la proposition incise est une proposition faisant partie d’une phrase complexe sans avoir de rapport syntaxique avec le reste de celle-ci. Cette proposition constitue une interruption dans l’organisation syntaxique dans laquelle elle apparaît, une intervention de l’énonciateur principal dans l’énoncé d’une autre personne ou dans son propre énoncé, dans divers buts.

Les paroles rapportées dans la question sont dites par M. de La Hourmerie, ce qui est indiqué par l'auteur dans une première incise :

> fit alors M. de La Hourmerie que le joli toupet de l’expéditionnaire avait démonté un moment ;

insérée entre une virgule et un point virgule, cette première incise indique à la fois qui parle et dans quel état d'esprit il se trouve.

On trouve dans la même tirade une deuxième incise :

> (et il souligna)

qui sert à indiquer le ton sur lequel sont dites les paroles qui vont suivre. L'auteur, s'exprimant cette fois à l'intérieur d'une parenthèse, nous indique que « il » (de La Hourmerie) dit les paroles qui suivent en insistant sur les mots<sup>1</sup>, ces paroles (qui sont prononcées par de La Hourmerie) sont retranscrites en italique, l'italique servant à indiquer que ces paroles sont dites avec insistance, ce qui est un usage reconnu de l'italique, comme indiqué d'ailleurs dans la question.

> Si monsieur (et il souligna), *qui est si exactement renseigné*, veut bien faire dès à présent le nécessaire, nul doute que je sois en état de vous satisfaire rapidement.

Ce qui peut, à la rigueur, sembler étrange, c'est que dans une même tirade Courteline adopte deux techniques différentes. L'auteur est libre de son style, le lecteur est libre d'apprécier ou non. Courteline utilise beaucoup les parenthèses, souvent pour faire des clins d’œil au lecteur. Et ce n'est pas l'unique fois dans ce texte<sup>1</sup> qu'il les utilise pour une incise, on trouve plus loin :

> Que d’hommes ! — je dis : en cette maison (déclamait maintenant Letondu, avec une majesté imposante), que d’hommes justement accusé...

Quant à ce qui est de doubler l'insistance, une fois dans l'incise, une fois dans la typographie de la parole prononcée, je n'y vois rien de surprenant. C'est pour moi la volonté de l'auteur de montrer qu'il faut attacher de l'importance à cette insistance.

---

<sub>Je ne réponds pas au .2 de la question, car je ne le comprends pas, la virgule étant déjà placée derrière la parenthèse, que veut dire ce 2. ? [J'ai demandé un éclaircissement](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53357/place-et-fonction-dune-expression-et-il-souligna-messieurs-les-ronds-de#comment112956_53357) mais je ne l'ai pas eu.</sub>

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> [Souligner](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/souligner) Accentuer ; mettre en valeur. ➙ appuyer.</sup> 
<sup><sup>2</sup> [Texte complet](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Messieurs_les_ronds-de-cuir/Texte_entier).</sup>

Comment: _Sembler étrange_? Je ne vois pas vraiment quoi que ce soit d'étrange. Je ne me serais posé aucune question en lisant ce texte, et j'aurais apprécié les incises qui donnent un peu plus de couleur.

Comment: @Frank Je me cite : « Ce qui peut, à la rigueur, sembler étrange... » (Remarque quand même combien je nuance : «  la rigueur ») . Tu ne lis pas que, moi,  je trouve ça étrange, n'est-ce pas ? Ça veut juste dire ce que ça dit, à savoir, que certains peuvent trouver ça étrange et c'est ma façon d'expliquer que le PO n'ait pas compris que c'était une incise !

Comment: oui, oui, j'ai bien compris. Je viens juste en appui pour montrer qu'il n'y a rien de vraiment étrange, pas de souci.

Comment: @Frank OUffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff

Comment: On peut aussi éventuellement l'interpréter comme "et il souligna (quelque chose sur le papier devant lui)" si le contexte s'y prête.

Comment: @guillaume31 Il suffit de lire le texte de Courteline pour voir que ce n'est pas du tout le contexte. Il est évident qu'on est dans un discours et que souligner est ici pris dans son sen figuré.

Comment: @None l'OP n'a pas donné beaucoup de contexte sur la conversation, ni de lien vers le texte original. Mon explication reste plausible, bien que moins que la vôtre, je vous l'accorde. Mon but n'était pas de minimiser la réponse, juste apporter une idée en plus.

Comment: @None Je ne la trouve pas mal posée. Il est parfois normal de demander plus de contexte. J'arrête ici pour ne pas alimenter la spirale d'agressivité inutile qui sévit  dernièrement ici, au mépris des règles de bienséance du site.